# How to filter table rows with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have made a table here : [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/R3nierjvr/x831ve3v/) but I seem unable to get my table filter to work. What I tried to do was create a menu at the top where a specific filter would only show those rows. I tried to use `.Data` for this.

Filter Row Script

```
$('.filterMenu a').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var c= $(this).data('qtype');
  $('#questTable')[0].className = c;
});
```

Row Hover Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.table-row').hover(function() {             
        $(this).addClass('current-row');
        }, function() {
            $(this).removeClass('current-row');
        });
    });
```

Row hide Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('tr')
    .filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)')
    .addClass('selected')
    .end()
    .click(function(event) {
        if (event.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
            $(':checkbox', this).trigger('click');
        }
    })
    .find(':checkbox')
    .click(function(event) {
        $(this).parents('tr:first').toggleClass('selected');
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/x831ve3v/8/) is a working example

The basic idea is to first hide all rows and then recursively show them, when they match your criteria.

Find all `tr` in `tbody` and hide them

```
var trs = $("#questTable").find("tbody tr");
trs.hide();
```

I would make use of the filter function

```
.filter(function (i, v) {})
```

to check if the row should be shown.

```
trs.filter(function (i, v) {
  if ($(this).data("qtype") == c) {
      return true;
  }
  if(c=="all"){
      return true;
  }
    return false;
})

//just show the row if it fits the criteria
.show();
```

Additionally I have fixed your typo msq -> mcq for the data-qtype in tr

**Edit**: Just updated the fiddle with more comments and fixed the thead area

Comment: Absolutly Brilliant Thx realy appreciate the fast response